# Query Datediff to output HH:MM in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I'm working with SQL Server 2012, and I have two columns `start` and `end` with `varchar(5)` values in `HH:MM` format.

The data looks like this

```
ID    Start       End
------------------------
1     00:00       06:00
2     06:00       16:00
3     16:00       18:00
4     18:00       24:00
```

My query is like this:

```
SELECT
    a.start,
    a.[end],
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.Start, a.[end]) / 60), 2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.Start, a.[end]) % 60), 2) AS TotalHours 
FROM
    TransactionActivity a
```

I exec the query with where clause based on ID number, it gives me the correct result, until in ID 4: i got error like this

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I think it because the End time value is 24:00, how can I make it to get the time difference?

Comment: when I try using replace, it gives me wrong TotalHours, let's say Start: 18:00, End: 24:00, then I replace, the result is 18:00 not 06:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off converting them into full datetime's (using an arbitrary date) because then the date functions will work correctly.

```
select
  a.[start]
  , a.[end]
  , RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(minute,a.[Start], a.[end])/60),2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(minute,a.[Start],a.[end])%60),2)
    as TotalHours   
from (
  select id
    , case when [Start] = '24:00' then dateadd(minute, 1, convert(datetime, '23:59')) else convert(datetime, [Start]) end [Start]
    , case when [End] = '24:00' then dateadd(minute, 1, convert(datetime, '23:59')) else convert(datetime, [End]) end [End]
  from TransactionActivity
) a
```